# Admin-Ajax call not working to implement star rating

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to implement a star rating in wordpress backend. i have succeded in implementing the system.now am trying to add the star rating to database while the stars are clicked using admin-ajax.

this is my html:

```
<li name="star" value="one" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">
```

on mouse click it calls addrating function where i have written my ajax, this is my ajax code:

```
function addRating(obj) {
    $('ul.rating li').each(function(index) {alert("hello");
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var rate=$('#rating').val((index+1));
        var postid=$(this).data('postid');
        if(index == $("ul.rating li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
        $.ajax({ url:"<?php echo site_url().'/wp-content/themes/options-framework-theme-master/register_ajax.php';?>",
                type:'post',
                data:{
                postid:'postid',
                rate:'rate'},
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            }
            });
    });
}
```

and this where the ajax call goes:

```
<?php 

    $id = $post['postid'];

    update_post_meta($post_id,'starrating',$_POST['rating']);    


 ?>
```

Ma issue is tht while clicking on the stars no ajax call is going.please help me , am kinda new in ajax.

Comment: What is `update_post_meta($post_id,'starrating',$_POST['rating']);`  
Just `echo` there what you want as response

Comment: the update function updates how many stars were selected in backend and convert it into int value and stores tht value in "starrating"

Comment: you need to create a custom ajax_action on the functions.php of your theme: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add ajax to wordpress, you can follow these steps:

**Step  1 : frontend (php file) the look**

```
 <li name="star" value="one" 
                            onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" 
                            onmouseout="removeHighlight();" 
                            onclick="addRating(this);">
```

**Step 2: In the javascript (validation and ajax call):**

```
function addRating(obj) {
    $('ul.rating li').each(function(index) {alert("hello");
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var rate=$('#rating').val((index+1));
        var postid=$(this).data('postid');
        if(index == $("ul.rating li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
        var url = "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        $.ajax({ url:url,
                type:'post',
                data:{
                postid:'postid',
                rate:'rate'},
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            }
            });
    });
}
```

**Step 3 : hook**
 An example :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_function_name', 'my_function_name');// for those connected to your app
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_function_name', 'my_function_name');// for everybody
```

**Step 4: Write the actual function to handle the backend logic(in functions.php or similar)**

```
 function my_function_name(){
  // my logic goes here
}
```

Good luck!